# Getting type error when using $ cond in KDB

Tags: kdb

I have a dictionary (testDict) in the following format with hostname and region of that hostname

```
`host1|`LDN
`host2|`NYK
```

I have a function to return region based on hostname

```
func1:{[hostname] testDict[hostname]}
```

When I execute the function, I get enlisted region

```
 func1[`host1]
 enlist`LDN
```

I am trying to assign some variables based on the value that is returned by this function but I am getting type error. I have tried both vector conditional and cond. Appreciate your input on this

```
$[enlist `LDN=func1[`host1]; connDetails:`:hostName:port:id:pass; connDetails:`:newHostName:port:id:pass]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things here. First, kdb+ reads right to left, so this:

```
enlist `LDN=func1[`host1]
```

compares LDN to the output of func1 and then enlists that result, rather than enlisting LDN before the comparison. Use parentheses to force the order of execution you want:

```
enlist[`LDN]=func1[`host1]
```

Secondly, `$` expects an atomic value in the conditional, your statement returns a 1 item list. You can use `first` to convert it to an atom:

```
q)type first enlist[`LDN]=func1[`host1]
-1h
```

Having said all of that, it looks like the real issue is that your dictionary is storing the values as 1 item lists, rather than atoms. You would be better off to store the atomic values, which will simplify everything for you.

```
q)testDict:first each testDict
q)$[`LDN=func1`host1;connDetails:`:hostName:port:id:pass;connDetails:`:newHostName:port:id:pass]
`:hostName:port:id:pass
q)$[`NYK=func1`host1;connDetails:`:hostName:port:id:pass;connDetails:`:newHostName:port:id:pass]
`:newHostName:port:id:pass
```

Or simpler still, just store the mapping from hostname to connection details as your dictionary and index that to get the result you want:

```
q)d:`host1`host2!`:hostName:port:id:pass`:newHostName:port:id:pass
q)d`host1
`:hostName:port:id:pass
q)d`host2
`:newHostName:port:id:pass
```

If you need a default connection string for hosts not in your dictionary, you can use fill (`^`):

```
q)`:default^d`host1
`:hostName:port:id:pass
q)`:default^d`host3
`:default
```